# How to plot several image tiles in new emty image object based on image tile name in python?

Tags: python, image, python-requests, python-imaging-library

I need to request several image tiles from a server and plot them in the new image object and save it as a jpg file.
Image tile name starts at its position in new image object: e.g. position:x0,y0 --> Tile name: 00
I know how to do https request, and how to create new empty image objects I can use PIL:

```
import requests
from PIL import Image

url = f‘https://myserver.com/GetTile/{tileKey}’
imageTile = requests.get(url)

image_sheet = Image.new("RGB", (8192, 4096))
```

Where I have stuck is how to horizontally loop over new image object to form the tile name, and later requesting from the server the tile and place it in the new image_sheet. And repeat the process until all tiles are on the place. When it is done save the result as a file.
Please help to the python noob.

Comment: You are missing quite a lot of details, like how the `tileKey` works and how the filenames actually work and how many there are and whether you know in advance how many you want...

Comment: @MarkSetchell tileKey is an imagTile name that I need to form by looping true the new image object. I also have a tile size:512 what means that on X-axis (8192/512) will be 16 tiles and Y-axis(4096/512) 8 Total: 128 tiles.

Comment: So presumably, you just want `for x in range(0,8192,512): ` followed by `for y in range(0,4096,512): ` and a `requests.get()` and a `paste()` ?

Comment: Yes. Something like that.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/61702854/2836621