# How to write several image tiles, from http request, into new image object in python?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I need to request more than 100 image tiles from a server and save it in the new empty image object in a sequence and save the result on disk.

I can easily do the request and save a single image tile with the following code :

```py
image_r = requests.get('https://myserver.com')
image = image_r.content
with open ('image.jpg', 'wb') as f
    f.write(image)
    f.close()
```

I have created an empty array to store all tiles from my request, but I am failing on looping over them and plotting to the new empty image object.

My tile size is 512x512, the empty image width and height are 9216x5120.

I need to plot is starting from `x0`, `y0` upper left corner.

To create the new empty image object, I used `PIL` library :

```
empt_image = Image.new("RGB", (9216, 5120))
```

I new in developing and I have tried to do the following :

```
empt_image = Image.new("RGB", (9216, 5120))

counter = 0
images = []
image_r = requests.get('https://myserver.com')
images.append(r_imageTile.content)
counter += 1
for (i, image) in enumerate(images):
    empt_image.paste(image, (0, 9216, 512), (0, 5120, 512))

empt_image.save("image.jpg")
```

which gives me the following error :

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'load'`
```

This error may be because my tiles are in bytes, but I am not sure.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/61630596/2836621

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't help me. I tried to save the tiles on my disk but received an error that `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'save'`